# ggplot2 applied to single row crashes R

Tags: r, ggplot2

When I execute the following code, R crashes.

```
require(ggplot2)
set.seed(2)
x <- rnorm(10,0,1)
set.seed(3)
y <- rnorm(10,0,1)
set.seed(2)
s <- runif(10,0,1)
set.seed(2)
c <- runif(10,0,1)
df <- data.frame(X = x, Y = y, S = s, C = c)
df.1 <- df[1,]
p <- ggplot(df.1, aes(X,Y))
pp <- p + geom_point(aes(size = 1, col=C))
print(pp)
```

Now, I think I understand why it would be reasonable for R to crash here. As I am only taking one row of data, `ggplot2` doesn't know which colour to use (there's nothing to compare). I would prefer that it didn't crash though. Adding `scale_colour_continuous()` does not prevent the crash. Is there a way to prevent this crash apart from ensuring that `df.1` has at least two rows?

Does anyone else experience this crash? I am using R 2.15.1 (64-bit) on a Windows machine.

Comment: `colour=C`, when `C` is not an integer seems to be causing the trouble.

Comment: `df.1 <- df[1:2,]` makes the plot run without crashing and produces the right result for me despite `C[1:2]` not being integer.

Comment: Yes indeed. on my r-session in Rstudio, this is what I get: `rsession[13530] <Error>: CGImageCreate: invalid image size: 1 x 0.` But I get the plot without session crash (R 3.0.1). But the legends are screwed up.

Comment: I believe the problem is `scale_color_continuous`. It probably tries to create a color gradient from only one value, which does not work for obvious reasons. `p + geom_point(aes(size = 1, col=factor(C)))` doesn't give a CGImageCreate error.

Comment: Works for me (2.15.3, Linux)

Comment: Works for me as well (though the point in the legend is black while the one in the graph is blue). R version 3.0.1 (2013-05-16),
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit), ggplot2_0.9.3.1

Comment: Cannot reproduce on Win7/64-bit, R 3.1.1, ggplot2_1.0.0.